# How do I change text in a Word Doc from Excel VBA when Word Doc is located on a server?

Tags: sharepoint, excel, replace, ms-word, vba

I have a macro that creates an experiment report based on a word template and then saves it to a remote server. A cell is selected in my Excel worksheet, the macro runs, an instance of Word  opens with a blank template, and the file is saved based on the selected cell and other data. What I want to do is edit the Heading in the blank template and update it to the name of the experiment which is located in the first column of the row of the selected cell.

The code below works when I open a file from my local files but does not work when the file is located on the server.

```
    Dim oWord As Object
    Set oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    oWord.Visible = True
    oWord.Activate

    ' Open a new instance of the ExperimentTemplate and save it
    oWord.Documents.Add Template:="ExperimentTemplate", NewTemplate:=False, DocumentType:=0
    oWord.ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:=fPath & "example.docx", FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument 'fPath is the path to the folder where file will be saved on the server
    oWord.ActiveDocument.Close

    ' Re-open file and change Experiment Name
    oWord.Documents.Open FileName:=fPath  & "example.docx"
    Set oSelection = oWord.Selection
    oSelection.Find.Text = "Experiment Name"
    oSelection.Find.Replacement.Text = name 'defined as the text in the first cell of the selected column
    oSelection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    oWord.ActiveDocument.Save
    oWord.Quit
    Set oWord = Nothing
```

I am aware that my code is not the most elegant but that is of little worry to me unless it is affecting the functionality I am trying to achieve. Any help would be greatly appreciated. This has been wrecking my head for two weeks now!

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work? Any error message?

Comment: When I run this locally, the text "Experiment Name" located at the top of the file is replaced with the text located in the first column of the row of the selected cell. But when I run this for the file created on the server, it seems to skip over the text replacement and "Experiment Name" remains at the top of the file. No changes occur within the file

Comment: Did you try to debug the code by stepping through it?

Comment: Yes, and the first problem is it does not select "Experiment Name" and as a result it cannot replace it

Comment: What do you get for `oSelection` when you check in the immediate window?

Comment: What happens if you try `Set oSelection = oWord.Content` or `Set oSelection = oWord.WholeStory`?

Comment: for both i get Run-time Error:438: Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: One moment. testing something

Comment: Try this `Set oSelection = oWord.Documents(1).Content`

Comment: I don't get any errors, but the text still does not change. A colleague of mine has just suggested creating the file locally, modifying it, and then uploading it to the server so this should work

Comment: What does `oSelection` return? Doesn't it contain the text that you are looking for?

Comment: Using `Set oSelection = oWord.Documents(1).Content`, `oSelection` returns all text in the document, but then `oSelection.Find.Text = "Experiment Name"` doesn't select that text

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can you try this code for me?

```
Dim oWord As Object
Dim oSelection As Object
Dim sel As Object

Set oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
oWord.Visible = True
oWord.Activate

oWord.Documents.Add Template:="ExperimentTemplate", NewTemplate:=False, DocumentType:=0
oWord.ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:=fPath & "example.docx", FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument 'fPath is the path to the folder where file will be saved on the server
oWord.ActiveDocument.Close

' Re-open file and change Experiment Name
oWord.Documents.Open FileName:=fPath  & "example.docx"

Set oSelection = oWord.Documents(1).Content

oSelection.Select

Set sel = oWord.Selection

With sel
    .Find.ClearFormatting
    .Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With .Find
        .Text = "Experiment Name"
        .Replacement.Text = Name 'Hope you have declared it somewhere?
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = 1 'wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        sel.Find.Execute Replace:=2  'wdReplaceAll
   End With
End With
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! i knew i was having problems around my text selection... Thanks a million for your help

Comment: @Malteaser6900: I am happy that it worked for you :)